# Syntax to Format Automatic Properties

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a typical C# automatic property.  How can I apply WebUtility.HtmlDecode() when I've only got a get; set;?

UPDATE:

Ok, dumb mistake of the day.  I had a weird issue where my web.config db connection string was pointed to the right server but for some reason since I had 2 instances (one sql 2008 and 2012) it was still picking up the instance of that DB in 2008 which had the encoding still there.  I had fixed the encoding issue by just decoding the Title via a unit test I created in the 2012 DB which in this case this whole fing post was unecessary in stack because the ultimate problem was it was reading from the old DB (messing me up).

Anyway I had already fixed this, finally got rid of the 2008 copy and now it's reading it fine after my fix:

```
  [Test]
    public void CleanAllPostEntries_DecodeHTML_DecodeWasSuccessful()
    {
        // Arrange

        // Act
        IEnumerable<Entry> posts = PostCRUD.GetAllPosts();

        foreach (Entry post in posts)
        {
            post.Title = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(post.Title);
            post.Body = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(post.Body);
            post.MetaTitle = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(post.MetaTitle);

            PostCRUD.UpdatePost(post);

            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("id: " + post.Id);
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("title: " + WebUtility.HtmlDecode(post.Title));
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("body: " + WebUtility.HtmlDecode(post.Body));
        }

        //Assert
        // TODO: add asserts
    }
```

So I don't think I need the decode afterall..I already did it!

Comment: Side note: I think it is generally bad idea to do something that makes property that was just set to not match value it was set to `item.Prop = value; if (item.Prop != value) { WHY??? }` . (+1 to Kuya John for an approach).

Comment: The value of a property shouldn't change once set. That's what you have methods for.

Comment: Out of curiosity. Where does the htmlencoded text come from?

Comment: coming from a DB, yea I probably should do the decode at the LOWEST level.  I'm just trying to hack this for now, it's just for my blog, I'll fix it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't want to do HTML encoding/decoding via properties, although you could if you wanted to. There are several problems with this:

1. You'll be taking that encoding/decoding hit on *every single access of the property*, be it reading or writing.
2. The HTML encode/decode is a "lossy" conversion and you only want to do it exactly once per string; you don't want to be constantly encoding and decoding and re-encoding the same string when you're tossing it around on multiple properties, you'll start to lose information that way.
3. The HTML encoding of the content is not a property of the object you're storing it with, it is a property of the content itself.

What you really want to do is use a stronger type that represents the HTML-encoded string.

The .NET 4.0 framework includes a `System.Web.HtmlString` type which you should use for this purpose. In fact, use the `System.Web.IHtmlString` interface if you wish to remain general.

Comment: sh** I just realized it was reading from a copy of my local DB.  So I didn't need to decode afterall because I had already fixed the problem by a unit test I had created to do a WebUtiilty.HtmlDecode on it and updated those values in the DB already.  So I was adding Decode when I didn't need to only because it was reading from an old copy of the DB where the encoding were still there.  Dumb.  But good info, giving you the answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can't, *I think*. The only way to do is to have a separate method that formats the value and assign it to the property, ex

```
private string SamplePropery {get; set;}
private string FormatMethod(string value) {}

private void SampleExecute()
{
    // format and set to property
    SampleProperty = FormatMethod("hello world");

    // get property and format the value
    string _value = FormatMethod(SampleProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of a property shouldn't change once set. It's supposed to return the same value you set. That's why it's called a property. Call `HtmlDecode` before you set the property value.

Should other people work with your classes and not have access to your source they wouldn't imagine you're doing any kind of processing when setting the property value.

Comment: Using/implementing stronger types like `HtmlString` to represent the encoding are a much better solution than mentally tracking the encoding state of a `string` being passed around to multiple functions.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it automatically with the magic getters and setters.  You need to create your own private property and use it as the backing store for your public properties.

Example:

```
private string _Item;

public string Item
{
    get
    {
        return _Item;
    }
    set
    {
        _Item = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(value);
    }
}
```

However, other answers to this question are correct that this is probably a bad idea. For example, if your code is ever used outside of an HTML application, you will have to HTML-encode all text before you set this property.

Comment: Bad coding technique. See my answer.

Comment: @Jeroen but at least I answered the question.  You said "don't do it" which I will admit is probably best practice, but is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @MosheKatz nonsense. "Don't do it" is a perfectly acceptable answer to the question of how to do something that is bad.

Comment: I even told him how it should be done. Calling the function before setting the property. How to implement that is up to him and depends on the rest of his code.